# How can I solve non-linear equation with two elements by fsolve?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a function which has some input parameters which are constant. However, I also have two elements `Hw` and `teta` that must be calculated. In fact, I have one equation with two unkonwns.

Input parameters:

```
D=0.030; 
A=7.0685*10^-4; 
Jo=0.763; 
Jw=0.778090833; 
ro_o=910; ro_w=1000; 
mu_w=0.001; 
mu_o=0.92;
```

`teta` needs to be calculated from an iterative process as:

```
(-2*pi*Hw)+teta-sin(teta)==0
```

after calculation of `teta` (initial guess in `[0 2*pi]`), we must put it in the following equation to solve for `Hw`, but the problem is `teta` itself is a function of `Hw` as well.

```
[Hw, fValue] = fsolve(@(Hw) (((8*ro_o*((D-(2*sqrt(Hw*A/pi)))*(Jo/(1-Hw))*ro_o/mu_o)^-1.0)*(((Jo/(1-Hw))-(Jw/Hw))*((Jo/(1-Hw))-(Jw/Hw))))*(pi*D/2*(2*sin(teta/2)+2*pi-teta)*(1/(1-Hw))))-((0.023*(((Jw*D*ro_w)/mu_w)^-.2)*ro_w*(Jw/Hw)^2*(pi*D))), 0.9);
```

I would be appreciated if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve for the roots of both equations simultaneously. [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) permits exactly this.

You need to turn your two scalar equations into a single vector equation:

```
D = 0.030; 
A = 7.0685e-4; 
Jo = 0.763; 
Jw = 0.778090833; 
ro_o = 910;
ro_w = 1000; 
mu_w = 0.001; 
mu_o = 0.92;

f = @(x)[-2*pi*x(2)+x(1)-sin(x(1));
         (8*ro_o*((D-2*sqrt(x(2)*A/pi))*(Jo/(1-x(2)))*ro_o/mu_o)^-1)* ...
         (Jo/(1-x(2))-Jw/x(2))^2*pi*D/2*(2*sin(x(1)/2)+ ...
         2*pi-x(1))/(1-x(2))-0.023*(Jw*D*ro_w/mu_w)^-0.2* ...
         ro_w*(Jw/x(2))^2*pi*D];
x0 = [pi;0.9];
[x, fValue] = fsolve(f, x0)
teta = x(1);
Hw = x(2);
```

which, for the initial guesses chosen, returns

```
x =

   3.182192078148883
   0.512921423233560
```

Choosing other initial guesses, such as `x0 = [0;0.9];` or `x0 = [2*pi;0.9];`, will return different solutions.

You may notice that I removed a bunch of superfluous parentheses from the anonymous function in your question – about 30 actually! Unneeded parentheses can make reading code more difficult and are not a substitute for being familiar with [operator precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) in Matlab. I also simplified some terms. You should check that it's still correct.

It's also a bad habit to use anonymous functions for long complicated equations. These are hard to read and debug and they are less efficient than regular functions. You should turn the anonymous function `f` above into a regular function, which would allow you to break the long part into meaningful terms. Then pass a handle to this new function to `fsolve`. If you want to pass in parameters to this new function, see [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) from the The MathWorks on parametrizing functions. I also think that you're probably misspelling the Greek variable name "theta" and possibly "rho" as well.